# How to plot charge defect formation energy diagram

Tags: density-functional-theory

How to plot charge defect formation energy vs Fermi energy.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, the other answer misses the context and does not help in the context of plotting defect formation energy diagram. In the context of calculating defect formation energy diagram, we vary the Fermi level as a free variable. The formula for defect formation energy is:
$$ E_f^D(q,E_F) = \left[E^D(q) + E^D_{corr}(q)\right]-E^{Pristine}-\sum n_i\mu_i + q(E_F + E_{VBM}^{Pristine}-\Delta V_{0/b}).$$
which has a form of:
$$ E^D_f(q) = q(E_F + A)+ B$$ where $A$ and $B$ have constant values for a particular charged state. From doing DFT calculation, we can get all of the terms as explained in this [answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/12557/6055). Then we can plot charged defect formation energy diagram using the following python code (courtesy of [Hosung Seo](https://notebook.rcc.uchicago.edu/files/srep20803/Doc/Tutorials/Defect_formation_energy.pdf), Galli Research Group, uChicago). Before running the code, one needs to prepare an input file with the DFT results as following (example is for N-vacancy center in AlN):

```
#Input file for defect formation energy calculations
#So far, I only consider defects in mono-atomic or binary crystals.
#Defects could be impurity, mono- or di-vacancy, and their complexes

&VBM        #(eV)
6.9696

&band_gap        #with respect to the VBM (eV)
5.0

&Host_type
Al N

&Vacancies  #For example, for divacancy in AlN, put 'Al N'
N

&Impurities

&Chemical_potentials #(eV)
Al  -99.7202664
N   -273.5905338

&Host_supercell_energy #(Ry)
-6585.061221

&Charge_state_range  #two integer numbers // make sure you have a right number of alignment term
-2 2

&Defective_supercell_energy # charge_state(q) and energy (Ry) 
-2  -6563.150785
-1  -6563.955569
0   -6564.730914
1   -6565.492659
2   -6566.044454

&Correction_terms #(eV), for each charge state (e.g. -2 to 2): short-range potential energy, and (E_iso - E_periodic)
-0.016  0.532248
-0.014  0.133062
0   0
-0.013  0.133062
-0.023  0.532248
```

```py
import sys
import numpy as np
import re
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class calculate_E_formation:
    """ calculate formation energy of a given defect with charge transition levels and plot it.
    expected to have input file such as Hf_vac_N_poor.in
    The output file, which will be named as, e.g. Hf_vac_N_poor.in_out can be used as input for the
    plot_multiple_formation_E class in this module"""

    def __init__(self, filein):
        """initialize an instance"""

        self.filein = filein
        self.fileout = filein + "_out"
        self.fileout_CTL = filein + "_CTL"

        self.VBM = 0.0
        self.band_gap = 0.0
        self.host_supercell_energy = 0.0
        self.host_type = 0  #1 - mono-atomic, 2-binary, 3-ternary crystal, etc.
        self.host_atom = []
        self.vacancies = []
        self.impurities = []
        self.charge_start = 0
        self.charge_end = 0
        self.chem_potentials = {} #dictionary type
        self.supercell_energy_list = []
        self.correction_terms_list = []

        # Read the input data
        self.read_data()
        self.n_charges = int(self.charge_end - self.charge_start + 1)
        self.supercell_energy = np.array(self.supercell_energy_list).reshape(self.n_charges, 2)
        self.correction_terms = np.array(self.correction_terms_list).reshape(self.n_charges, 2)

        # Write the formation energy for each charge state
        self.energy_step = 0.01 # eV
        self.energy_part = 0.0  # eV
        self.charge_dependent_part = 0.0 # eV
        self.fermi_level = []   #x-axis Fermi-level
        for i in range(0,int(self.band_gap/self.energy_step)):
            self.fermi_level.append(i * self.energy_step)
        self.all_data = np.array([])  # will stack actual the data array in self.write_data().
        self.formation_energy_data = [] #the lowest energy value for a given fermi level

        self.write_data()

        self.CTL_list = []   #charge transition levels
        self.CTL_list = self.find_CTL() #read the self.formation_energy_data point-by-point, see where the slope changes.
        self.CTL_count = int(len(self.CTL_list)/2)
        self.CTL_array = np.array(self.CTL_list).reshape(self.CTL_count,2)

        # Plot the formation energy
        self.plot_data()

    def read_data(self):
        with open(self.filein, 'r') as data_file:
            for line in data_file:
                if "&VBM" in line:
                    tmp_line =  data_file.readline()
                    self.VBM = float(tmp_line)
                elif "&band_gap" in line:
                    tmp_line = data_file.readline()
                    self.band_gap = float(tmp_line)
                elif "&Host_type" in line:
                    tmp_line = data_file.readline()
                    re_findall = re.findall(r"[\w]+", tmp_line)
                    self.host_type = len(re_findall)
                    for i in range(0, len(re_findall)):
                        self.host_atom.append(re_findall[i])
                elif  "&Vacancies" in line:
                    tmp_line = data_file.readline()
                    re_findall = re.findall(r"[\w]+", tmp_line)
                    for i in range(0, len(re_findall)):
                        self.vacancies.append(re_findall[i])
                elif "&Impurities" in line:
                    tmp_line = data_file.readline()
                    re_findall = re.findall(r"[\w]+", tmp_line)
                    for i in range(0, len(re_findall)):
                        self.impurities.append(re_findall[i])
                elif "&Host_supercell_energy" in line:
                    tmp_line = data_file.readline()
                    self.host_supercell_energy = float(tmp_line)
                elif "&Charge_state_range" in line:
                    tmp_line = data_file.readline()
                    self.charge_start = int(tmp_line.split()[0])
                    self.charge_end = int(tmp_line.split()[1])
                elif "&Chemical_potentials" in line:
                    chk = True
                    while chk == True:
                        tmp_line = data_file.readline()
                        tmp_line_split = tmp_line.split()
                        if len(tmp_line_split) > 1:
                            self.chem_potentials[tmp_line_split[0]] = float(tmp_line_split[1])
                        elif len(tmp_line_split) == 0:  # hit the end of the chem_potential data.
                            chk = False
                        elif "&" in tmp_line:
                            print( "Warning: there should be a space between every section. \n")
                            chk = False
                        else:
                            continue
                elif "&Defective_supercell_energy" in line:
                    for i in range(self.charge_start, self.charge_end+1):
                        tmp_line = data_file.readline()
                        if i == int(tmp_line.split()[0]):
                            self.supercell_energy_list.append(int(tmp_line.split()[0])) #charge state
                            self.supercell_energy_list.append(float(tmp_line.split()[1])) #supercell E
                        else:
                            sys.exit("check the charge state range and defective supercell \
                                energy\n")
                elif "&Correction_terms" in line:
                    for i in range(self.charge_start, self.charge_end+1):
                        tmp_line = data_file.readline()
                        self.correction_terms_list.append(int(i))   #charge state
                        self.correction_terms_list.append(float(tmp_line.split()[0])) #short-range
                else:
                    continue

    def write_data(self):
        Ry = 13.605692  #eV
        for i in range(0, self.n_charges):
            q = self.charge_start + i   # e.g. -2, -1, 0, 1, 2
            print ("\n" + "charge_state =" + str(q) + "\n")

            if q == self.correction_terms[i,0]: # Should contain the charge state, q.
                E_correction = self.correction_terms[i,1]
                print ("E_correction = " + str(E_correction) + "\n")
            else:
                sys.exit("Check the self.correction_terms np array. The first column should contain\
                    the charge state.\n")

            if q == self.supercell_energy[i,0]:
                Energy_part = self.supercell_energy[i,1] *Ry +E_correction -1*self.host_supercell_energy*Ry
                print ("Energy_part = " + str(Energy_part) + "\n")
            else:
                sys.exit("Check the self.supercell_energy np array.\n")

            formation_energy =  Energy_part + q* self.VBM
            #add the chemical potential parts.

            if self.vacancies:
                for c in self.vacancies:
                    formation_energy = formation_energy - (-1)* self.chem_potentials[c]
                    print ("chem_potential for " + str(c) + " (vacancy)  has been added. \n")
                    print ("Energy_part + q* VBM + chem_pot (so far) = " + str(formation_energy) + "\n")
            else:
                print('no vacancies are present\n')
            if self.impurities:
                for c in self.impurities:
                    formation_energy = formation_energy - (+1)* self.chem_potentials[c]
                    print ("chem_potential for " + str(c) + " (impurity)  has been added. \n")
                    print ("Energy_part + q* VBM + chem_pot (so far) = " + str(formation_energy) + "\n")
            else:
                print('no foreign impurities are present \n')

            data_list =[]

            for j in range(0,int(self.band_gap/self.energy_step)):
                data_list.append(formation_energy + q* self.fermi_level[j])

            if len(self.all_data) == 0:
                self.all_data = np.append(self.all_data, np.array(data_list))
            else:
                self.all_data = np.vstack((self.all_data, np.array(data_list)))

        for i in range(0,int(self.band_gap/self.energy_step)):
            tmp_array = self.all_data[:,i]
            minimum_E = np.sort(tmp_array)[0]
            self.formation_energy_data.append(minimum_E)

        with open(self.fileout, 'w') as fout:
            for i in range(0,int(self.band_gap/self.energy_step)):
                fout.write('{0:<15.7f} {1:<15.7f} \n'.format(self.fermi_level[i],\
                    self.formation_energy_data[i]))

    def find_CTL(self):
        #find the charge transition levels where the slope changes
        CTL = []
        slope_to_compare = self.charge_end
        slope_threshold = 0.5
        delta_x = self.energy_step

        fout_str = str(self.filein) + "_CTL"
        with open(fout_str, 'w') as fout:
            fout.write("charge transition levels for " + str(self.filein) + "\n")

        for i in range(1, int(self.band_gap/self.energy_step)):
            delta_y = self.formation_energy_data[i]-self.formation_energy_data[i-1]
            slope = delta_y/delta_x
            #print("slope = " + str(slope) + "\n")
            slope_diff = slope_to_compare - slope
            if abs(slope_diff) < slope_threshold:
                continue
            else:
                print("CTL from" + str(slope_to_compare) + " to " + str (slope_to_compare - 1) + " = " + \
                    str((self.fermi_level[i-1] + self.fermi_level[i])/2.0) + "\n")
                CTL_point = self.fermi_level[i-1] + delta_x/2.0
                CTL.append(CTL_point)
                CTL_energy = self.formation_energy_data[i-1]+slope*delta_x/2.0
                CTL.append(CTL_energy)
                with open(fout_str, 'a') as fout:
                    fout.write('{0:<3d} to  {1:<3d} = {2:<10.5f} \n'.format(slope_to_compare,\
                        slope_to_compare-1, CTL_point))
                slope_to_compare = slope_to_compare - 1
        return CTL

    def plot_data(self):
        x_data = self.fermi_level
        x_min = self.fermi_level[0]
        x_max = self.fermi_level[int(self.band_gap/self.energy_step)-1]+self.energy_step

        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
        axes = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        axes.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=15)
        axes.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=12)
        plt.xlim (x_min, x_max)
        #plt.ylim(0,3)

        #plot all data
        for i in range(0, self.n_charges):
            q = self.charge_start + i   # e.g. -2, -1, 0, 1, 2
            y_data = self.all_data[i,:]
            label_str = fr'$Cu_{{Zn}}$ with q={q}'
            axes.plot(x_data, y_data, '-', label=label_str)

        #plot the lowest-energy data on top
        y_data = self.formation_energy_data
        axes.plot(x_data,y_data, color = "k"  , linewidth = 3, linestyle = '-')

        axes.legend(loc=0)

        axes.set_xlabel('Fermi level (eV)', fontsize = 18)
        axes.set_ylabel('Defect formation energy (eV)', fontsize = 18)
        axes.set_title(self.filein, fontsize = 18)

        x_CTL_data = self.CTL_array[:,0]
        y_CTL_data = self.CTL_array[:,1]
        axes.plot(x_CTL_data, y_CTL_data, color = 'b', marker = '.', markersize = 4 , mew =  4)

        fig.savefig(str(self.fileout)+'.png')
        plt.legend(prop={'size': 18})
        plt.show(fig)

class plot_multiple_formation_E:
    """ plot multiple formation energies together.
        there should be a input file, containing the name of each formation energy file
        and y_min and y_max
        For example, prepare a file, named as plot_together_Hf_La.in
        In the file,
        Hf_imp_C_poor.in_out
        Hf_vac_C_pool.in_out
        La_imp_C_poor.in_out
        La_vac_C_poor.in_out """

    def __init__(self, filein, x_min=None, x_max=None, y_min=None, y_max=None):
        """initialize an instance"""
        self.filein = filein
        self.x_range_chk = False
        if x_min != None:
            self.x_range_chk = True
            self.x_min = x_min
            self.x_max = x_max
        else:
            self.x_min = 0.0
            self.x_max = 10.0

        self.y_range_chk = False
        if y_min != None:
            self.y_range_chk = True
            self.y_min = y_min
            self.y_max = y_max
        else:
            self.y_min = 0.0
            self.y_max = 10.0

        self.plot_all()

    def plot_all(self):
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
        axes = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        with open(self.filein, 'r') as fin:
            for line in fin:
                f_name = re.findall(r"[\w.]+", line)[0]
                print("Adding the following to the plot: " + f_name + "\n")
                data = np.genfromtxt(f_name)
                x_data = data[:,0]
                y_data = data[:,1]
                axes.plot(x_data, y_data, '-', label= f_name)
        axes.legend(loc=0, fontsize=20)
        axes.set_xlabel('E - E_VBM (eV)', fontsize = 18)
        axes.set_ylabel('Formation Energy (eV)', fontsize = 18)
        axes.set_title('Defect Formation Energy', fontsize = 20)

        if self.x_range_chk:
            plt.xlim(self.x_min, self.x_max)

        if self.y_range_chk:
            plt.ylim(self.y_min, self.y_max)

        fig.savefig(str(self.filein) + '.png')
        plt.show(fig)
```

and run the code by doing:

```py
# For a single charge state
calculate_E_formation('dfe.in')
# For multiple charge state (which you are looking for, I believe)
plot_multiple_formation_E('multiple_dfe.in')
```

Check the docstring of the corresponding function to learn more about the input file syntax. Just from the total energy of the pristine supercell, defect supercells, VBM, correction terms (if any, otherwise set 0), and chemical potentials (total energy of the elemental forms), the above code can generate the following types of figures:

[image]
[image]

Comment: The question is very generic and hence I have provided a basic and a broad answer. Calling the answer "not helpful at all" is harsh. Please consider being a bit more polite in your answers.

Comment: @VandanRevanur Thank you for pointing that out. I did not want to be harsh and I apologize for that. I have reworded my response. The first code you provided is for plotting any y-vs-x values. The second code you provided is wrong in this case because charged defect formation energy is not the same as the formation energy per atom. Defect formation energy is not available in MaterialsProject. It needs to be plotted from DFT results as shown in my answer

Answer (score 4):

If you already have a set of defect energies and Fermi energies then it is as simple as plotting them with visualizing library such as matplotlib.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Sample data (replace with your actual data)
fermi_energies = [-2.0, -1.5, -1.0, -0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0]  # Fermi energies (x-axis)
defect_energies = [0.1, 0.08, 0.05, 0.02, 0.0, 0.03, 0.06, 0.09, 0.12]  # Charge defect formation energies (y-axis)

# Plot the data
plt.plot(fermi_energies, defect_energies, marker='o', linestyle='-', color='b')
plt.xlabel('Fermi Energy (eV)')
plt.ylabel('Charge Defect Formation Energy (eV)')
plt.title('Charge Defect Formation Energy vs Fermi Energy')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image: Sample defect vs fermi E]

If you would like to obtain the values of the defect and fermi energies, then you can use an online database such as the Materials Project Database.
You can sign up for free and will be given an API-key.

Below is a code to access the values for a couple of elements and then plot them:

```
from mp_api.client import MPRester

# Replace with your Materials Project API key (sign up at materialsproject.org)
api_key = "YOUR_API_KEY"

# Create an instance of the Materials Project API
mp = MPRester(api_key)

# Example: Get Fermi energy and defect formation energy for Silicon (Si)
formula = "Si"

formulas = ['Si', 'C', 'O', 'P', 'B', 'N', 'F']

fermi_energies = []
defect_energies = []
for formula in formulas:

  # Query the Materials Project database for the data
  data = mp.summary.search(formula=formula, fields=["efermi", "formation_energy_per_atom"])

  # Extract Fermi energy and defect formation energy
  fermi_energy = data[0].efermi
  defect_energy = data[0].formation_energy_per_atom

  fermi_energies.append(fermi_energy)
  defect_energies.append(defect_energy)


# Plot the data
plt.plot(fermi_energies, defect_energies, marker='o', linestyle='-', color='b')
plt.xlabel('Fermi Energy (eV)')
plt.ylabel('Charge Defect Formation Energy (eV)')
plt.title('Charge Defect Formation Energy vs Fermi Energy')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]